# Modify a packet's content on DD-WRT

Tags: router, dd-wrt, sniffing, packet

I need to modify incoming data to my network. Specifically, I want to modify all responses from a specific internet site so it doesn't show a certain HTML element.

Is this possible with DD-WRT/OpenWRT firmware?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you specifically trying to accomplish? A web filter of sorts?

Comment: Not on a big scale, but yes, parts of a certain page shouldn't even be sent to the browser for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

DD-WRT has basic filtering features (Proxy, Cookies, Java Applets, and ActiveX). If you want more, take a look at setting up a proxy server. [This wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Transparent_web_proxy) walks you through the process of setting this up.